# Zoom In - Out doesn´t work correctly

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have implemented 3 buttons to allow the user to zoom in, zoom out, and go back to the default size.

The script works to do the zooming in and out, but I still have 2 issues I can't solve.

**First problem:**

Every time on zoom in, the image to do the zoom still arrives the limits of my window, when the image doesn't have any space to the left and right, it stretches the image to the top and to the bottom.

**Second Problem:**
I can't set the onclick handler on the button to go to the default size.

I hope someone can give me a hand with this.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yn6rp/1/)

**My Code:**

**HTML:**

```html
<div id="thediv"> 
  <img id="pic" src="images/2.png"/>
</div>
<input type="button" value ="-" onclick="zoom(0.9)" id="minus"/>
<input type="button" value ="+" onclick="zoom(1.1)" id="plus"/>
<input type="button" value ="1" onclick="zoom(1.1)" id="1" style="margin-left:80px;position:fixed;bottom:0px;"/>
```

**CSS:**

```css
#thediv {
    margin:0 auto;
    height:auto;
    width:1005;
    overflow:hidden;
    }

#thediv img {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}
#minus{position:fixed;bottom:0px}
#plus{position:fixed;bottom:0px;margin-left:40px;}
```

**Javascript:**

```js
window.onload = function(){zoom(1)}

function zoom(zm) {
img=document.getElementById("pic")
wid=img.width
ht=img.height
img.style.width=(wid*zm)+"px"
img.style.height=(ht*zm)+"px"
    img.style.marginLeft = -(img.width/2) + "px";
    img.style.marginTop = -(img.height/2) + "px";
}
```

Comment: The fiddle isn't working for me.

Comment: @isherwood: To get the fiddle working change 'onLoad' to 'No wrap - in <head>' in the side drop-down

Comment: i can zoom the image, but still got my problems which i have mentioned before in my description above

Comment: Well for zooming to the default size (which I assume is what the '1' button is for) that will not work because zoom(1) just scales the image to the current size. Instead, you would probably want to store the image size on load and then reset it to those values when desired.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are saying with your first problem.

Comment: what i means is that i have two things that i try to do which doesn´t working at this time.. Hope you can help me a little bit with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### HTML

```
<div id="thediv">
    <img id="pic" src="http://cdn.crunchify.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/java_url.jpg" />
</div>
<button type="button" id="minus">-</button>
<button type="button" id="plus">+</button>
<button type="button" id="reset">1</button>
```

I've removed `onclick` and bound event listeners to the `button`s in the JavaScript.

### JavaScript

```
// For the "reset" (1) button to work, you must store the default size somewhere
var defaultWidth = document.getElementById("pic").width;
var defaultHeight = document.getElementById("pic").height;
var resetZoom = function () {
    var img = document.getElementById('pic');
    img.width = defaultWidth;
    img.height = defaultHeight;
};

var zoom = function (zm) {
    'use strict';

    var img = document.getElementById("pic");

    img.width *= zm;
    img.height *= zm;
};

document.getElementById('minus').addEventListener('click', function () {
    zoom(0.9);
}, false);

document.getElementById('plus').addEventListener('click', function () {
    zoom(1.1);
}, false);

document.getElementById('reset').addEventListener('click', function () {
    resetZoom();
}, false);
```

1. I've added the `resetZoom()` function, which works differently than `zoom()`.
2. I've also simplified the `zoom()` function to directly modify the
   `width` and `height` properties of the [`HTMLImageElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement). You can add the fancier stuff (`style` and stuff) if you wish.
3. The three event listeners beneath are bound to the buttons to trigger a function on the `click` event. In this case, it performs `zoom` and `resetZoom`, respectively.

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yn6rp/4/).

Answer (score 1):

[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/yn6rp/5/)!

Since you're doing everything in the head, I added an `onload` function instead of your `window.onload`, which wasn't working. I also added a `toDefault` function that puts the image back to the original size/position

**Updated HTML**

```
<body>
<div id="thediv">
    <img onload='load()' id="pic" src="http://cdn.crunchify.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/java_url.jpg" />
</div>
<input type="button" value="-" onclick="zoom(0.9)" id="minus" />
<input type="button" value="+" onclick="zoom(1.1)" id="plus" />
<input type="button" value="Default" onclick="toDefault()" id="one" style="position:fixed;bottom:0px;margin-left:80px" />
</body>
```

**Updated javascript**

```
var origHeight, origWidth;
function load () {
    var image = document.getElementById("pic");
    origHeight = image.offsetHeight + 'px',
    origWidth = image.offsetWidth + 'px';
}

function toDefault() {
    var image = document.getElementById("pic");
    image.style.height = origHeight;
    image.style.width = origWidth;
    image.style.marginLeft = -(image.width / 2) + "px";
};

function zoom(zm) {
    var img = document.getElementById("pic"),
    wid = img.width,
    ht = img.height;
    img.style.width = (wid * zm) + "px"
    img.style.height = (ht * zm) + "px"
    img.style.marginLeft = -(img.width / 2) + "px";
    //img.style.marginTop = -(img.height / 2) + "px";
}
```